# Remove spaces in dbf file/lib

Tags: python, dbf

I need to filter a dbf file using the python `dbf` lib. I made a class with some methods over the dbf lib, so I have a method `search` that filter records.

```
def search(self, field_name: str, value: object) -> List:
    self._open_for_read()
    index = self._table.create_index(lambda rec: getattr(rec, field_name))
    records = index.search(match=(value,))
    return records
```

The problem is, either the `dbf` lib add blank spaces, or my dbf file contains blank space that I cant see.

So, to query a field named `desceng` that contain `Mattress`, I need to add blank spaces.

```
 records = hifis.search('desceng',  'Mattress                                                                        ')
```

The number of blank spaces seems to depend on field.

Is there a way to remove the blank spaces, so I can simply query with `'Mattress'` instead of `'Mattress        '`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things you can do:

- trim the trailing whitespace when you create the index:

  `index = self._table.create_index(lambda rec: (getattr(rec, field_name) or '').strip())`
- use the `Char` class when opening the database as it automatically trims trailing whitespace:

  `self._table = dbf.Table(..., default_data_types={'C':dbf.Char}`